# How to get values from multiple dropdowns from local storage?

Tags: javascript, jquery, local-storage

I have three dropdowns:

[image]

I try to write the options' values to the local storage to keep the selected values after refreshing the page.

```
        function populateStorage() {
                localStorage.setItem('university', document.getElementById('university').value);
                localStorage.setItem('faculty', document.getElementById('faculty').value);
                localStorage.setItem('department', document.getElementById('department').value);

                getUpdatedStorage()
            }

            function getUpdatedStorage() {
                document.getElementById('university').value = localStorage.getItem('university');
                document.getElementById('faculty').value = localStorage.getItem('faculty');
                document.getElementById('department').value = localStorage.getItem('department');
            }

            if(!localStorage.getItem('university')) {
                populateStorage();
            } else {
                getUpdatedStorage();
            }
```

Here's the code running at each сhange event:

```
       $('#university').change(function() {
                let universityId = $(this).val();

                $('#faculty').find('option').not(':first').remove();

                $.ajax({
                    url: 'exam_sheet/faculty/' + universityId,
                    type: 'get',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: function(response) {
                        if(response['data'] !== null) {
                            for(let i = 0; i < response['data'].length; i++) {
                                let facultyId = response['data'][i].subd_id;
                                let facultyName = response['data'][i].subd_short_name;

                                let option = `<option value='${facultyId}'>${facultyName}</option>`;

                                $('#faculty').append(option);

                                populateStorage();

                            }
                        } else {
                            return false;
                        }
                    }
                });
            });
    
    $('#faculty').change(function() {
                let facultyId = $(this).val();

                $('#department').find('option').not(':first').remove();

                $.ajax({
                    url: 'exam_sheet/department/' + facultyId,
                    type: 'get',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: function(response) {
                        if(response['data'] !== null) {
                            for(let i = 0; i < response['data'].length; i++) {
                                let departmentId = response['data'][i].subd_id;
                                let departmentName = response['data'][i].subd_name;

                                let option = `<option value='${departmentId}'>${departmentName}</option>`;

                                $('#department').append(option);

                                populateStorage();

                            }
                        } else {
                            return false;
                        }
                    }
                });
    
      $('#department').change(function() {
                let departmentId = $(this).val();

                $.ajax({
                    url: 'exam_sheet/group/' + departmentId,
                    type: 'get',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    cache: true,
                    success: function(response) {
                        if(response['data'] !== null) {
                            for(let i = 0; i < response['data'].length; i++) {
                                let groupId = response['data'][i].stg_id;
                                let groupName = response['data'][i].stg_name;

                                let option = `<option value='${groupId}'>${groupName}</option>`;

                                $('#group').append(option);

                                populateStorage();

                            }
                        } else {
                            return false;
                        }
                    }
                });
```

As you can see, the values are saved in the local storage.

[image]

But after refreshing the page the values aren't displayed as expected and look the following:

[image]

I'm new at using local storage and want to know how to solve the problem.